# Velocity gradient in fluids

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, kinematics

I am mathematician and I am interested to know more about fluid mechanics. I need an explanation of the physical meaning of the derivative of velocity with respect to position.

Comment: You may want to provide some context for when this comes up.

Comment: The derivative of velocity with respect to position is the velocity gradient, and is related to the local rate at which the fluid is deforming and rotating.

Comment: Why don't you read Fluid Dynamics by G.K. Batchelor, which is written for people with applied math background?

Answer (score 0):

When considering a *steady* flow field there is no time dependence so changes in fluid (infinitesimal) particle trajectories, velocity and acceleration depend only on position along the potential lines, largely influenced by the space, boundary conditions (geometry).

See [Potential Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow) for more detail relating physics and the mathematical models.

Answer (score 0):

As a very basic example consider you are doing rough river rafting.

The flow of water is fast at downwash areas past a big boulder and turbulent at windy bottlenecks or in conjunction of two streams wher it roars and dissipates a lot of energy, and slow at calm areas.

while you are riding your raft you feel the pull and push and sideway drags of the flow jerking you around and, if you are not harnessed, toss you out of your raft even!

If you graph the speed of the river as an XYZ surface its partial derivatives along different paths are acceleration!